# Addition of Pager View breaks scrolling with Maestro on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-native-pager-view, maestro

I'm seeing a total failure of our Maestro tests because of the recent addition of a carousel/pager on the home screen - Maestro seems unable to scroll at all, either by `scroll` or `scrollUntilVisible`, with the carousel present. Since it's at the top of a long page, this breaks most of our tests.

Details:

- This is only occurring on iOS; Android runs fine.
- We're using React Native, and a package, [react-native-pager-view](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-pager-view), which relies on [UIPageViewController](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uipageviewcontroller), for the carousel/pager.
- If I comment out the carousel, all works as expected.

Does anyone have any idea why this might be happening, or a workaround?
Or, failing that, some way to move the page down beyond the carousel without using `scroll` or `scrollUntilVisible`? (I looked at `travel`, but not sure if that could be used for this.) If I manually scroll the emulator past it and then run `scroll` in Maestro Studio, it works again, so any way of getting the page past the carousel would probably work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue seems to be that `react-native-pager-view`'s implementation of `UIPageViewController` doesn't seem to play nice with Maestro's `scroll` and `scrollUntilVisible` commands.

Instead, use [swipe](https://maestro.mobile.dev/api-reference/commands/swipe) to swipe past the element, then `scrollUntilVisible` will work fine.

```yaml
- runFlow:
    when:
      platform: iOS
    commands: 
    - swipe:
      start: 50%, 75%
      end: 50%, 55%
```

- Note: Turns out this isn't Maestro-specific; the pager breaks scrolling on *actual* iOS devices too. (Surprise surprise - when Maestro says you have a bug, you actually do.) So rather than using this workaround, you might wish to use a different pager implementation, or just go with a Flatlist.